# How do I restore a Windows 8 iso image to a USB disk in OS X?

Tags: macos, windows-8, usb-flash-drive, iso-image

I am on OS X and have a Windows 8 Consumer Preview x64 image. My computer doesn’t have a CD drive (MacBook Air). I have a 4 GB USB drive. I want to restore that image to the USB drive. There are many tools to do that on Windows, but I can’t finger out how to do it in OS X. Please note that I can’t run a VM, as my Air is a limited use machine.

What I’ve tried:

- Simply restore to USB.
- Convert the image to img and use `dd`.

These don’t work.

How do I go about doing this?

EDIT: Ok, everyone, really sorry for the confusion. I am new here.

To clear my motive, I am trying to create a bootable USB Windows 8 installer to install Windows 8 Consumer Preview (which apparently requires a product key, something I don’t have) so that I can use it later to install Windows 8 CP on my Mac Book Air. Using Bootcamp, according to what I have read and tried, is not an option. As suggested, I tried using Boot Camp Utility to prepare the USB drive, but unfortunately, that simply isn’t working and I can’t troubleshoot it.

Comment: Why not dd the ISO...? Should work as `dd if=/Users/username/Downloads/w8.iso of=/dev/sdX` with images, some people try to specify a partition # where really you should do the disc so it acts as a udf volume. Also, please clarify "didn't work", meaning they did not boot or writing the image to USB failed...?

Comment: Besides using dd, also ensure the partition has the boot flag set.

Comment: `dd`ing the ISO didn't help. I am on OS X and disks there are referred to as `/dev/diskX` and I wasn't specifying a partition number. Didn't work means didn't boot. All commands report that they are successful, but the disk can't be mounted. Booted up an Ubuntu Live USB and GParted says that there isn't a partition table on the drive. Weird.

Comment: You should be able to use pretty much any tool to place the iso on the thumbdrive.  Since you have a Windows installation I would use the Windows 7 tool that exactly this just on a Windows 8 iso.

Comment: @duci9y Yes, there would not be any partition table shown on the drive after dd, it would look like a UDF volume (similar to a CD).

Comment: @Ramhound I know about that tool, but the thing is, I don’t have a Windows installation!

Comment: @nerdwaller But as there’s no partition table, I can’t install a boot loader, so it doesn’t boot.

Comment: @duci9y That's odd, typically it wouldn't be required if it looks like a CD (which has the autorun functionality built in).  You know anyone with an external disc drive, or have a friend with Windows? Other option would be to install VirtualBox and mount the USB into the VM, then use the USB Creator tool from MS and then you should be well on your way.

Comment: Virtualisation is not an option. My Air has a processor without virtualisation support, and I am travelling right now, so I don’t even have friends here.

Comment: @duci9y - Why are you trying to use a beta version of Windows 8?  I figured you were trying to update Customer Preview to the RTM build.

Comment: I want to try Windows out. I did not buy it. The most legal thing was to download a Consumer Preview.

Comment: @duci9y - You can use Windows 8 Enterprise Trial which has a 90 day time limit. You cannot expect us to help you with a beta build of a released product.

Answer (score 3):

**Prepare the USB key**

We’re going to wipe the partition structure on the USB key. WARNING! THIS WILL DESTROY ALL DATA ON THE KEY!

Open up Disk Utility (it’s in /Applications/Utilities/).

Now do the following:

1. Select the USB key (select the root device, not its partitions)
2. Select the partition section at the top
3. Change the Scheme to 1 Partition
4. Change the Format to Free Space
5. Click Apply

You will get a confirmation dialog appear ensuring you really want to delete all data on the key, choose Partition.

Once it’s completed you can quit out of Disk Utility.

*The purpose of doing this is mainly to ensure that the USB key is in a consistent known state and also to ensure that any volumes are not mounted by OS X. It is not required and you can skip it if you’d rather just unmount the volumes yourself.*

**Preparing the ISO image**

Now that our USB key is ready, we need to get our .iso image into a format that we can copy to it. Open up a Terminal (it too is in /Application/Utilities, and I’ll assume you know how to use the terminal)

Now, convert the image from a ISO to a [Read/Write Universal Disk Image Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Disk_Image_Format#Data_format) (or UDRW). Here I’m using the xbmc live repack ISO, but you can use anything else that’s an ISO file.

```
(#503:14u:0s) evan@8thwonder[/Users/evan/Downloads]: hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o xbmc-9.11-live-repack.img xbmc-9.11-live-repack.iso Reading XBMC_Live (Apple_ISO : 0)… ......................................................................................................................................................................................................... Elapsed Time: 24.475s Speed: 20.0Mbytes/sec Savings: 0.0% created: /Users/evan/Downloads/xbmc-9.11-live-repack.img.dmg
```

Once completed this will create the .img file. The hdiutil function likes to append a .dmg suffix to the file so it will probably end up .img.dmg after conversion.

**Copy the image to the USB key**

We’re finally here. The easy part, actually copying the image to the USB key.

First run diskutil list to get a listing of the disks in your machine so you can identify the USB key. It will look like this:

```
(#504:14u:0s) evan@8thwonder[/Users/evan/Downloads]: diskutil list /dev/disk0 #: TYPE NAME SIZE IDENTIFIER 0: GUID_partition_scheme *250.1 GB disk0 1: EFI 209.7 MB disk0s1 2: Apple_HFS Macintosh HD 249.7 GB disk0s2 /dev/disk1 #: TYPE NAME SIZE IDENTIFIER 0: *1.0 GB disk1
```

Here mine’s /dev/disk1.

*We want to use the RAW disk device so that our copy will happen much faster because the RAW disk device provides unbuffered access to the device (See this Apple mailing list post for more info). This is accomplished by simply prepending ‘r’ to the device so that /dev/disk1 is going to become /dev/rdisk1*

Next we use the dd command to copy the image over.

```
(#506:14u:0s) evan@8thwonder[/Users/evan/Downloads]: dd if=./xbmc-9.11-live-repack.img.dmg of=/dev/rdisk1 bs=1m
```

On the command line we specify the Input File using if= and the Output File using of= and dd will copy the data from input to output, block by block.

Once it’s completed you can exit Terminal and remove the USB key from your OS X machine, it should now be able to bootup your ISO on another machine.

**NOTE:**  I wish I could take a credit for this, but I can't, here is the [source](http://evan.borgstrom.ca/post/1314205955/osx-bootable-usb-from-iso).

Comment: This method was already tried, coincidentally from the exact same guide.

Comment: @duci9y - Even if it worked you still need a product key.  Have you tried the Windows 8 Enterprise iso?

Comment: @duci9y Well, at least I tried!  Good luck!

Comment: +1 for rdisk#.  I always wondered why dd was so slow on Apple computers..

Comment: Remember to use `unmountDisk` before `dd`. `rdisk` will not work if it is mounted.

Answer (score 2):

The [Bootcamp](http://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp/) utility will do this for you.

**Edit:** Are you trying to run Windows 8 from the USB drive? I think we were all reading your question as if you wanted to install from the USB drive. However, based on your claim that you don't want to install Windows, I'm wondering if you are looking for Windows To Go, which would allow you to boot and run Windows 8 from the USB drive without having it installed on the machine.

If that's what you're trying to do, then [this article explains the process.](http://tweaks.com/windows/52279/how-to-create-a-windows-to-go-usb-drive/) You'll need a 32 GB or larger USB 3.0 drive and a machine that already has Windows 8 installed on it, so this might not work for you since you want something that runs on your Macbook Air and OS X.

Also, I believe [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/) will run on a machine that doesn't have hardware support for virtualization. Have you looked into that.

One other thing to note, there is a 90-day trial available for Windows 8 RTM, which might be a better option than the Consumer Preview if you just want to try it out. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/evalcenter/jj554510.aspx?wt.mc_id=MEC_132_1_4

Comment: I don’t want to install Windows, I want the installer image on a USB drive.

Comment: @duci9y - If you don't want to install Windows, then what purpose, does the installer image on the USB drive serve exactly?

Comment: Bootcamp requires a product key, which I don’t have. I want to try out Windows, and got the Consumer Preview from “other” sources.

Comment: @duci9y I don't recall Bootcamp requiring a product key just to prepare the USB key with the install image. Of course, you would need a product key to install Windows, but as Ramhound asks, what are you going to do with the installer image if not install Windows?!?

Comment: @DennisPalmer Unless Windows 8 added this, you do not need a key to install.  Solely to activate; however, you have 30 days until that is required. (Again, at least on W7, Vista and XP)

Comment: @nerdwaller Windows 8 does require the product key during the install, you cannot skip this step any longer. Also, I remembered I tried to do exactly what the asker is doing, on OSX it just doesn't work to extract it to a USB stick, burn a DVD or use a Windows machine.

Comment: @Brutick Thanks for the heads up, good to know.  Seconded, the hassle really isn't worth it for the OP.

Comment: I suggest the author try doing what he tried with an Windows 8 Enterprise 8 Trial ISO.  The customer preview unlikely wouldn't even activate and the activation process CANNOT be skipped in Windows 8.

Comment: Guys, I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, just with Windows 7. However, I believe the problem (and the solution) is the same.

As none of the answers I found on the internet worked for me, here are the steps that I ended up following.

First of all, brief description of my setup:

- I want to install Windows 7 (32-bit) on a PC (not on a Mac) using a USB removable media (8GB)
- I have an ISO image of the installation DVD
- I want to prepare the USB media on my Mac (OS X 10.10 Yosemite)
- my MacBook Pro only has USB 3.0 ports

What I tried:

- the typical suggestion of using `hdiutil` to convert ISO to UDRW IMG and then using `dd` to copy it to the USB. While I did not encounter any errors, the resulting USB media was not bootable.
- using `UNetbootin` to create the media (supplying Windows installer ISO as custom ISO). While I did not encounter any errors and the resulting USB media seemed to be bootable, it just crashed during boot (started to boot then halted the system, no error).
- using Windows inside VirtualBox to write to the USB stick did not work either, as VirtualBox does not support USB 3.0 yet (I even updated by VirtualBox to 5.0.0 RC1 but still no luck. Maybe newer versions will work)

**SOLUTION**

As none of the above worked, I ended up first [installing Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx) and then used that Ubuntu installation (it has GRUB2!) [to create a bootable USB stick](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-with-ubuntu).